# difference between response.selector.xpath and response.xpath

Tags: scrapy

From a performance standpoint, I would like to know the difference between

```
response.selector.xpath
```

and

```
response.xpath
```

Is there a case where a new http request is made and not the other one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

They are the same.

If you look into [Scrapy code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/response/text.py#L119), `response.xpath()` actually uses `selector.xpath()`.

```
def xpath(self, query, **kwargs):
    return self.selector.xpath(query, **kwargs)
```

> Is there a case where a new http request is made and not the other
>   one?

Neither one generate a new http request.